# One page layout for a PHP webpage

Tags: javascript, php, web

I want to make a one page layout for my webpage.
And I want to make that so, when i click a button in my navigation bar, it to display a div i've created for my content, but normally is hidden. Also, when i click on the logo of the page, the page goes to it's original state (without the content div showing).

I have no idea how to do this.

I guess your using Javascript and / or PHP for this?

Can you guys give me an example how to do this?

Example: http://www.basjansenmedia.nl/

Comment: No. You will have to do that yourself and then show what you have done and ask specific questions. Also view source at basjansen and see how he did it

Comment: There's plenty of information for this. Just Google some! Look in the source code for basjansenmedia.nl to start with

Answer (score 0):

When you go to [themeforest](http://themeforest.net/), there's a separate category called [One Page](http://themeforest.net/tags/onepage) themes. Do have a look at it. Or, why not you Google it for yourself? Anyways, a few tutorials would be:

- [One Page](http://themeforest.net/tags/onepage)
- [15 Useful HTML5 Tutorials and Examples For Beginners](http://www.scratchinginfo.com/15-useful-html5-tutorials-and-examples-for-beginners/)
- [Coding a CSS3 & HTML5 One-Page Website Template](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/02/html5-css3-website-template/)
- [Single Page Apps with AngularJS Routing and Templating](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use jquery

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    $('#myNewDiv').show();
    $('#myOldDiv').hide();
}
($'#logo').click(function() {
    $('#myOldDiv').show();
    $('#myNewDiv').hide();
}
```